# Perl : Read directory until a file is there

Tags: perl

I am writing a simple program to check for existence of file in a directory. The file is created by some external program with no uniform time. So, I need to check for the existence of file in a loop as I need to process it as soon as it borns.

This program runs continuously, even if the file has been created.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $dir = "/my/path";
opendir( my $dh, $dir ) || die "can't opendir $dir: $!";
my @files = grep { /^[^\.]/ && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir($dh);
until (@files) {
    print "No files Found: Sleeping for a sec\n";
    sleep(1);
    @files = grep { /^[^\.]/ && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir($dh);
}
print @files;
```

The below program worked as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $dir = "/my/path";
opendir( my $dh, $dir ) || die "can't opendir $dir: $!";
my @files = grep { /^[^\.]/ && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;
until (@files) {
    opendir( my $dh, $dir ) || die "can't opendir $dir: $!";
    print "No files Found: Sleeping for a sec\n";
    sleep(1);
    @files = grep { /^[^\.]/ && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir($dh);
    closedir $dh;
}

print @files;
```

I want to know difference between both of these two approaches. Why the former one didn't work even though I am reading the directory every time in a loop. Why I need to open the directory every time in a loop to make it work?

Comment: Because in first program You used opendir once then you are trying to read files from old $dh so it doesn't contains the latest information about file & In second program it does.

Comment: Have a look at [Filesys::Notify::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::Notify::Simple).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because after [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) the directory handle reached the end of the filelist so there is nothing more to read the next time, even if a file is added in the meanwhile. This happens on the first read when the handle is used in the list context.

You can add a call to [rewinddir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rewinddir.html) to the loop, which moves the directory handle back to the beginning of the directory for the next `readdir`.

Or, use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) and put the test right in the `until` condition

```
my $cond = qr(^[^\.]); 

until (grep { $cond && -f } glob "$dir/*") { 
    say "no files"; 
    sleep 1;
}
```

This way the directory is re-read for every test. Since `glob` returns the path this simplifies things.

It can also be shortened to

```
my @files;

sleep 1 until @files = grep { $cond && -f } glob "$dir/*";

say for @files;
```